# `Minimize` keeps running

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to determine the effect of small changes in one parameter of my problem on the KKT multipliers. The program computes the values of those multipliers (`γVec`) and then modifies one of the parameters slightly (by `ϵ`) to evaluate its impact on `γVec`. Initially we have `ϵ=0` to determine the "true" values for `γVec` and the solution is obtained. However, when `ϵ>0`, `Minimize` keeps running and does not return any value.

I've included two `Print` instructions to check the system being minimized and the solution obtained. In the first pass (`ϵ=0`), it prints both the minimization problem and the solution. In the second (`ϵ=1/5`), it prints the problem (just prior to `Minimize`) and never reaches the second `Print` instruction.

A minor issue is that I get an error message `Solve::ratnz` even though the code includes `Quiet[Solve::ztest1, Solve::ratnz];`.

My code follows

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
T = {{2, 3}, {3, 2}, {1, 4}};
αVec = ConstantArray[5/6, 3];
λVec = Array[λ, 3];
γVec = Array[γ, 2];
onesVec = ConstantArray[1, 3];
FactorNeeds = Transpose[T].λVec^(1/αVec);
Quiet[Solve::ztest1, Solve::ratnz];

minKL = 108516/148889
maxKL = 188939/48306

prodmarg = {};

steps = 10;
maxdif = 10^-4;

Do[ 

 fin = False;
 ϵ = 0;

 While[¬ fin,

  TCalc = MapAt[# - ϵ &, T, 
Flatten[{Position[Transpose[T][[2]], Min[Transpose[T][[2]]]], 2}]];
  FactorNeeds = Transpose[TCalc].λVec^(1/αVec);

  zerosVec = ConstantArray[0, Length[λVec]];

  Print["Problem: ", 
  MatrixForm[{FactorNeeds[[1]], λVec.onesVec == 1, 
 FactorNeeds[[2]] == i*FactorNeeds[[1]], 
 onesVec >= λVec >= zerosVec}]];

  temp = Flatten[
 Minimize[{FactorNeeds[[1]], λVec.onesVec == 1, 
   FactorNeeds[[2]] == i*FactorNeeds[[1]], 
   onesVec >= λVec >= zerosVec}, λVec, 
  Reals]][[2 ;; 4]];

  kVec = N[FactorNeeds /. temp ];

  Print["Solution: ", kVec];

  varVec = Flatten[{λVec, γVec}];
  zerosVec = ConstantArray[0, Length[varVec]];
  temp = N[γVec /. 
 Flatten[Solve[{D[λVec.onesVec - γVec.(FactorNeeds- kVec), {varVec}] == zerosVec, onesVec >= λVec >= {0, 0, 0}},
    varVec, Reals]]];

  If[ϵ == 0,
   actualprod = temp;
   prevchange = temp;
   ϵ = 1/5,
   currchange = (temp - actualprod)/ϵ;
   If[Max[Abs[currchange - prevchange]] < maxdif, 
    AppendTo[prodmarg, 
 Flatten[{ϵ, kVec, actualprod, currchange}]]; 
    fin = True,
    prevchange = currchange];
   ϵ = ϵ/5];
  ]
  , {i, minKL, maxKL, (maxKL - minKL)/steps}]
```

Comment: Is it a trading robot? Check how the parameter `currchange` is calculated in the loop

Comment: @AlexTrounev, no it's not a robot. It's just an illustration to highlight some issues in production. I don't think `curchange` can be the problem. The program stalls while executing `Minimize` (in which `currchange` plays no role) when $ϵ=1/5$, even though it ran smoothly when $ϵ=0$.

Comment: This is not a problem, use `NMinimize[]`

Comment: Thanks, @AlexTrounev I've tried and it works!

Comment: You're welcome!